# If have found that holding down CTRL + ALT whilst a macro is running, causes it to run faster. Can anyone explain why this might be?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have written a considerable number of macros for Microsoft Word running on Windows 10.

One macro in particular takes lines of text from a Word.Table in one Word.Document, copies them to Word.Paragraphs another Word.Document, and formats them with various Word.Styles.

The use case is that the macro is writing a contract for me, from a table of template clauses.

Normally, this runs quite slowly, as there is a lot of work going on underneath, both in selecting template clauses, and formatting; and I have optimised later when possible.

However, by chance I found that if I held down the CRTL + ALT key whilst the macro was running, the speed seemed to increase by 2x or more.

I observed this through the speed by which Debug.Print messages appeared when tracking the progress of the macro, and anecdotally have seen the same effect on other macros I have written.

It seems an unlikely quick win or free lunch.

Has anyone else encountered this for their own macros, or am I imagining things?

Answer (score 0):

Pressing this key combination must be turning ScreenUpdating off.

Comment: Thank you.  I hadn't thought of that.  I will compare with actively setting ScreenUpdating property in the code, and report back.

Comment: After some unscientific playing around, it really is working for me, albeit undocumented (so I can't rely on it). Even code with ScreenUpdating turned off runs quicker.  It is all relative of course, depending on what else is consuming CPU at the time.  I haven't scientifically measured the effect, but instinctively it feels like CTRL+ALT is supressing some process or other that would otherwise slow the Macro. I won't get round to "proving" this effect as I would need to set up a clean system with no other background processes consuming CPU. But it feels real for me at least.

Comment: Man, to be frank with you, it was a wild guess. Thanks for your follow up. I have done some research on the net to confirm my answer but could not find anything. I upvoted your question as it is worth it in view of your investigation effort. I wish you the best in your endeavors.

Comment: Hi, I totally get that, and thank you for the upvote and best wishes.

Comment: I have a further update to this.  Another suspect is accessing the Shading object of a Cell.    I use VBA to check if a cell has a particular shading (which excludes that cell from some further processing).   I have changed strategy, and now exclude cells using text content rather than shading, which has resulted in a large speep-up.  In doing so, I have found through testing that Word is extremely slow in accessing the Shading object and its properties; but the Ctrl-Alt seems to speed it up!  All very odd.

Comment: Hum... interesting. Thanks for the update!

Comment: The more I look at this, I think I'll let it drop.  My suspicions are with how CTR+ALT is affecting (a) screen updating (as you suggested), and (b) DoEvents (which I use too liberally to not block the UI),  Accessing the Shading object is also a factor (terribly slow).  I have achieved the speed-up I needed through (a) not using Shading unless essential, (b) being more discerning about when and why I am using DoEvents.